# Request ParameterNames() and adding to collection object

Tags: java, servlets, collections

I am getting form data from JSP page in the following format

```
qryStr[0][Value]:EMPNAME
qryStr[1][Search]:jack
qryStr[2][filter]:or
qryStr[3][Value]:EMPNO
.......
.......
```

I am using `Enumeration enum = request.getParameterNames()` and checking whether String contains String `qryStr`

What I would like to do is if string contains `qryStr` then I would like to add it to some kind of collection object and construct a query.

What is the best approach for this?

Query code snippet

```
select * from my_table
WHERE contains (my_col,'jack 
INPATH (/HELPER/EMPNAME)') > 0
```

If user selects values like `qryStr[0][Value]:EMPNAME`, `qryStr[1][Search]:jack`, `qryStr[2][filter]:or`, `qryStr[3][Search]:jill` then query would look like

```
select * from my_table
WHERE contains (my_col,'jack or jill
INPATH (/HELPER/EMPNAME)') > 0
```

If user selects values like `qryStr[0][Value]:EMPNAME`, `qryStr[1][Search]:jack`, `qryStr[2][filter]:or`, `qryStr[3][Value]:SUPERVISOR` then query would look like

```
select * from my_table
WHERE CONTAINS(my_col,'jack INPATH(/HELPER/EMPNAME) and jill 
INPATH(/HELPER/SUPERVISOR)') > 0;
```

Comment: can you show what a query could look like base on the data you posted?

Comment: @A4L I have included query code snippet. My Query is slightly complicated and that is the reason why I am trying to use a collection. Query has to be constructed based on value I receive and I need to check values are null or not.

Comment: The result query you are showing is not quite clear. Can you explain how you came to it from your original data? Where is the `filter` and the other `Value` in it? And where are `EMPNAME` and `jack` in all that? Do you mean `contains (my_col,'||jack||' INPATH (/HELPER/'||EMPNAME||')') > 0`?

Comment: @A4L Sorry for the confusion, I have corrected my query.

Comment: No worries! what about the filter and the other values?

Comment: @A4L  I have edited my question. My problem is values I receive from application are not in any kind of sequence

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40479/discussion-between-polppan-and-a4l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry: request.getParameterMap()) {
    String parameterName = entry.getKey();
    if (parameterName.startsWith("qryStr")) {
        // do what you want with the parameter name and its values
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I read this sequentially in the order it is inserted to Collection?

Comment: Read what? Which collection?

Comment: Sorry I got misunderstood.

Comment: Edit your question. I can't see your code, so I can't tell why it causes this compilation error.

Comment: When I add your code which you have posted then I am getting `interface java.util.Map not allowed here`

Comment: Except I don't have any idea what "here" refers to in this error message. You can't tak code and paste it wherever you want, and hope it will work fine. Code that is valid inside a method is not necessarily valid inside a class. Note that I had a typo, now fixed, in my code: I missed a closing parenthesis.